# Longest collatz sequence using dynamic programming

Tags: c, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve longest collatz sequence problem under 1000000 with the below code.  Can anyone suggest a faster way to approach this problem?  I was thinking of dynamic programming, but I'm having trouble in understanding it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long int col(long long int n)
{
    if(n==1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if(n%2==0)
            return (1+col(n/2));
        else
            return (1+col(3*n+1));
    }
}

int main()
{
    long long int i=0, c, max, k=1;
    max=1;
    for(i=1; i<1000000; i++)
    {
        c=col(i);
        if(c>max)
        {
            max=c;
            k=i;
        }
    }

    printf("%lld",max);
    printf("\n%lld\n",k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you don't mind to use memory, could have a container, say `int cache[1000] = {0};`, and save in every element of the container the `collatz chain length` when starting with that number. Using this `cache` could stop calculating a lot of `collatz chain length` when encounter an already calculated number.

Comment: This looks a lot like a solution for https://projecteuler.net/problem=14 . If it is, this could be included in the question and the question could have the relevant project-euler tag.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it appears you are having a bit of trouble getting things off-the-ground, so to speak. Let's start with the basics. Let's name your file `collatz.c` and after a quick glance, it looks like it should compile:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o ctz collatz.c
```

Good, it compiled with no errors and no warnings. Now let's see if it will run:

**output:**

```
$ time ./ctz
525
837799

real    0m2.088s
user    0m2.082s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Also good, `max` is 525 and `k` is 837799 and it completed in less than 2.1 seconds. The logic is implemented in a single recursive function akin to that used by a non-math-lib power function, so no great speed improvements come to mind. As was pointed out, there are optimization that can help reduce the execution time. Let's try the suggested `-Ofast -fwhole-program`:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o ctz collatz.c -Ofast -fwhole-program
```

**output:**

```
$ time ./ctz
525
837799

real    0m0.480s
user    0m0.474s
sys     0m0.003s
```

A 400+% improvement. That's better. So it looks like your work is done. Drop a comment or edit your question if you have more specifics in mind.

Comment: ...although there's no optimization!

Comment: With `-Ofast -fwhole-program` of gcc 4.8.3, it takes only 634ms 561ms 46ms (real/user/sys)

Comment: Your computer is much much faster than this old box.

Comment: Oh, sorry :) but in your case the time will be also decreased with optimization. It takes 1488ms 1419ms 31ms without optimization in my case >o<

Comment: (after seeing edit) Hey, the *really* slow box was mine! (It's okay, because it's actually not mine; it's my school's >o<)

Comment: Good call, the optimization reduced the time. I was thinking more from a logic than optimization standpoint :)

Comment: @ikh Can you think of any more? I'm pretty much out of thoughts on this one...

Comment: It's enough; `-O2` is widely-used for optimization, and `-O3` is faster one. `-Ofast` is much faster one, with some floating-point behavior against standard. (As you know, OP's code doesn't have any floating point.) And `-fwhole-program` lets the compiler know we're compiling *whole* program (not `gcc a.c -c` `gcc b.c -c` and `gcc a.o b.o`, but `gcc a.c b.c`), so compiler can optimize on level which is similar to (or higher than) link-time optimization regardless of future linking. For more information, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Answer (score 1):

I took the suggestion from NetVipeC and modified your program a bit.  The changes were:

1. I used a #defined constant `MAXNUM` to control the number of iterations.
2. I added a `result` array to store previous results.
3. In the `col` function, it now ends when it finds a previous result, instead of just stopping at 1.

## The Modified Program

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXNUM  1000000

unsigned short result[MAXNUM];

long long int col(long long int n)
{
    if (n < MAXNUM && result[n] != 0)
        return result[n];
    if(n%2==0)
        return (1+col(n/2));
    else
        return (1+col(3*n+1));
}

int main()
{
    long long int i=0, c, max, k=1;
    max=1;
    result[1] = 1;
    for(i=2; i<MAXNUM; i++)
    {
        c=result[i]=col(i);
        if(c>max)
        {
            max=c;
            k=i;
        }
    }

    printf("%lld",max);
    printf("\n%lld\n",k);
    return 0;
}
```

I also went ahead and rewrote your program to remove recursion, add in a small optimization, and allow the max to be set by a command line argument:

## The Rewritten Program

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define DEFAULT_MAXNUM        100000000

static uint16_t *result;

uint16_t collatz(uint64_t n)
{
    uint64_t originalNumber = n;
    uint16_t count          = 1;

    while (1) {
        if (n & 1) {
            n = n*3+1;
        } else {
            n >>= 1;
            if (n < originalNumber)
                return count + result[n];
        }
        count++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint64_t i         = 0;
    uint16_t count     = 0;
    uint16_t bestCount = 1;
    uint64_t bestNum   = 1;
    uint64_t maxNum    = DEFAULT_MAXNUM;

    if (argc > 1) {
        maxNum = strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 0);
        if (maxNum < 2)
            maxNum = 2;
    }

    result = malloc(maxNum * sizeof(result[0]));
    if (result == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Not enough memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    result[1] = 1;
    for(i=2; i<maxNum; i++) {
        count = result[i] = collatz(i);
        if (count > bestCount) {
            bestCount = count;
            bestNum   = i;
        }
    }

    printf("Max considered: %" PRIu64 "\n", maxNum);
    printf("Largest number: %" PRIu64 "\n", bestNum);
    printf("Largest count : %d\n", bestCount);
    return 0;
}
```

## The Timing Results

Here are the timing results from the three programs.  Note that I used 100000000 as the number of iterations (100x the original amount) to get longer run times.  I also used `gcc -O4` to build all programs.

```
Original program : 37.7s
Modified program :  2.0s
Rewritten program:  1.2s
```